# Postgresql evolutions Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state. ERROR: syntax error at or near "User" Position:12 [ERROR:0, SQLSTATE:42601]

Tags: java, postgresql

but there is no "User" i removed it but still getting the error. I removede that entity class and chnaged to Login but still getting the same error.

this is my entity class Logins.java

```
package models;

import io.ebean.Model;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import io.ebean.*;
import play.data.format.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="logins")
public class Logins extends Model {
    @Id
    private String Login;
    @Constraints.Required
    private String Password;

    public Logins(){}
    public Logins(String name,String pass){
        this.Login=name;
        this.Password=pass;
    }
    public static Finder<String,Logins> find = new Finder<>(Logins.class);

    public String getLogin(){
        return this.Login;
    }
    public void setLogin(String name){
        this.Login=name;
    }
    public String getPassword(){
        return this.Password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String pass){
        this.Password=pass;
    }

}
```

evolution script 1.sql generated automatically . i tried deleting the file and refreshing web page same error i am getting.

```
# --- Created by Ebean DDL
# To stop Ebean DDL generation, remove this comment and start using Evolutions

# --- !Ups

create table logins (
  login                         varchar(255) not null,
  password                      varchar(255),
  constraint pk_logins primary key (login)
);


# --- !Downs

drop table if exists logins cascade;
```

Answer (score 0):

Play store database evolutions on "play_evolutions" table. When you have sql error, it's stored with a last_problem field.

So :

1. Delete all lines with a content on last_problem column

```sql
DELETE FROM "play_evolutions" WHERE "last_problem" != '';
```

2. Restart sbt / play application

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).